# Justification of taking limit under an integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

In the solution of a complex analysis problem I'm working through the following comment was made:

$\displaystyle-\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\pi}^{0} i e^{i\epsilon \displaystyle e^{i \theta}} d\theta = \pi i, \;\;\;\;\;$ since the limit can be taken under the integral sign...

I'm not sure how to justify this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$|\exp(i\varepsilon e^{i\theta})| = e^{-\varepsilon \sin\theta},$$
the integrands are bounded by an integrable function, independently of $\varepsilon$.

Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem shows that the limit is $-i\pi$, since the integrand converges pointwise to $i$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.